# how can i convert postscript files (ps) to pdf with hyperref

Tags: postscript

URGENT ***

ps (postscript) file to pdf document with hyperref and without hyperref

can any one help me to find good tool to convert ps to pdf with hyperref. i wants my files

(ps) to be converted as pdf file with hyperref

Im using winedt 8.0 now ,

adobe distiller is not available in market now,

so im in need of another distiller to do this.

Comment: If you load `hyperref`, the links will be preserved in the `ps2pdf` step.

Comment: Could you explain a little more exactly what workflow you use, and perhaps include a minimal working example of the type of LaTeX input you have?

Comment: im using latex code to produce tex file and convert to .dvi file and verify the output. the i using dvi_>pdf option in my latex editor to prepare pdf file. but its not included hyperref links enabled.

Comment: adobe distiller is not available in market now, so im in need of another distiller to do this.